# Find different pair in a list by python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have a list and I want to find different pair in list.
I implement a function --> **different()**

```
import numpy as np


def different(array):
    res = []
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in array:
        if (x1, y1) != (x2, y2):
            res.append([(x1, y1), (x2, y2)])
    return res


a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
              [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
              [[7, 9], [6, 3]],
              [[3, 3], [3, 3]]])

out = different(a)  # get [[(1, 2), (3, 4)],
                    #      [(7, 9), (6, 3)]]
```

Is there any other better way to do it?
I want to improve my function **different**.
List size may be greater than 100,000.

Comment: I want to filter duplicate pairs

Comment: How big is the list? There are different approaches, base on how big the list is.
Also - you want the duplicates or the different pairs?

Comment: Does the result have to be tuples?

Comment: List size may be greater than 100,000

Comment: You want an exact algorithm or a probabilistic one with arbitrarily low error would do?

Comment: I want an exact algorithm. thanks.

Comment: Ah, you are talking about every tuple pair! I thought it was about every possible tuple combination.

Comment: @user3483203 Results can also be stored in numpy array

Comment: If you had tuples, you could have use `set()`

Comment: @vincentlai, my answer was incorrect. The `logical_and` has to be replaced by a `logical_or`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numpy way to do it is

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
              [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
              [[7, 9], [6, 3]],
              [[3, 3], [3, 3]]])

b = np.logical_or(a[:,0,0] != a[:,1,0],  a[:,0,1] != a[:,1,1])

print(a[b])
```

Comment: This is the faster one @coldspeed, by a landslide, I'm running a batch of timeit tests. 5 minutes and the results are in.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti And also happens to hardcode the indices and work for arrays with two columns only?

Comment: Well, if that is OP situation that's fine. I'm **absolutely not** saying that yours is a bad answer and you have my vote, I was going for that one myself, I was just blown away by the speed difference. @joe's answer works in the micro seconds, yours in the milliseconds. It's *x20* times slower.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I don't know, what did you test it on?

Comment: I'm realising an extended answer collecting all times and explaining the setup.

Comment: @coldspeed posted! I hope it explains fully how I ran the tests. Do let me know if it was done correctly.

Comment: This solution fails to identify `[[1,2],[1,3]]` as different while OP's does flag it.

Comment: You are right, the `logical_and` has to be a `logical_or`. Fixed.

Answer (score 6):

#### Vectorized Comparison

```
a[~(a[:, 0] == a[:, 1]).all(1)]

array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]],

       [[7, 9],
        [6, 3]]])
```

This works by taking the first pair of each subarray and comparing each one with the second pair. All subarrays for which entries which are not identical *only* are selected. Consider,

```
a[:, 0] == a[:, 1]

array([[False, False],
       [ True,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]])
```

From this, we want those rows which do not have True at each column. So, on this result, use `all` and then negate the result.

```
~(a[:, 0] == a[:, 1]).all(1)
array([ True, False,  True, False])
```

This gives you a mask you can then use to select subarrays from `a`.

---

#### `np.logical_or.reduce`

Similar to the first option above, but approaches this problem from the other end (see DeMorgan's Law).

```
a[np.logical_or.reduce(a[:, 0] != a[:, 1], axis=1)]
```

Comment: `np.logical_or.reduce` seems to me the best solution since it is the fastest that has the same behaviour as OP function with partially different pair lists.

Answer (score 3):

## Solutions time comparisons

When there are so many different approaches to a problem, time comparisons can really help sort out the better answers.

### Setup

We use an array of size `(200000, 2, 2)` as [OP Vincentlai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9061561/vincentlai) pointed out that is in the range of the expected array size.

```
a = np.array(np.random.randint(10, size=(200000, 2, 2)))
```

---

---

### Using [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7919597/joe) answer: [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html)

```
%timeit b = a[np.logical_and(a[:,0,0] != a[:,1,0],  a[:,0,1] != a[:,1,1])]
>>> 5.12 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

### Using [Coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/coldspeed) first answer: vectorised comparison

```
%timeit b = a[~(a[:, 0] == a[:, 1]).all(1)]
>>> 13.7 ms ± 559 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

### Using [Coldspeed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4909087/coldspeed) second answer: [`numpy.logical_or`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_or.html)

```
%timeit b = a[np.logical_or.reduce(a[:, 0] != a[:, 1], axis=1)]
>>> 13.2 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

### Using [U9 Forward](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8708364/u9-forward) answer: filters

```
%timeit b = list(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1],a.tolist()))
>>> 102 ms ± 4.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

---

### Using [aydow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5491375/aydow) answer: filters

```
%timeit b = [[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)] for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in a if (x1, y1) != (x2, y2)]
>>> 752 ms ± 11.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

---

### Conclusions

Joe's approach with [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) is by far the faster one. Predictably, every full python approach falls extremely short to anything numpy.

Comment: I believe the accepted answer should be [`Joe's`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7919597/joe), as it is the one that works best. This is just an answer comparison. Thank you though!

Comment: If you're going to submit answers that are just timings of other people's code, really should be something like a community wiki

Comment: Also on Joe's answer you're timing the creation of the mask, but not the indexing itself

Comment: @user3483203 right, I'm fixing it asap, sorry. If possible, would you explain me how this can become a wiki? I never wrote one. Also, this was thought as an answer comparison, helpful to discern which of the answers was best.

Comment: Please when down voting try to explain why. If there is something wrong with the answer, it would benefit both me and those who read it for the error to be fixed.

Comment: @user3483203 I've informed myself and I've converted the post to a community wiki.

Comment: The results of my were incorrect for some cases. The `logical_and` had to be a `logical_or`. Could you repeat the speed test?

Comment: Sure, I'll execute the tests asap.

Answer (score 1):

Try using **`filter`**:

```
import numpy as np

def different(array):   
   return list(filter(lambda x: x[0]!=x[1],array.tolist()))

a = np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
              [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
              [[7, 9], [6, 3]],
              [[3, 3], [3, 3]]])

out = different(a)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

By using list comprehension in one line we can do like as below,

```
items_list = [[[1, 2], [3, 4]],
              [[1, 2], [1, 2]],
              [[7, 9], [6, 3]],
              [[3, 3], [3, 3]]
             ]

# Output
[itm for itm in items_list if itm[0] != itm[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension

```
def different(array):
    return [[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)] for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in array if (x1, y1) != (x2, y2)]
```